# Deciphering compiler error for binding tuple values

Tags: f#

For

```
subs
|> Array.map (fun x ->
               let t, s, _ = x
               getAuditEventsAsync s t (now - TimeSpan.FromDays(7.0)) now)
```

the compiler says for `t` when applying `getAuditEventsAsync`:

```
The type 'string' does not match the type 'string * string'
```

`getAuditEventsAsync` is a `string -> string -> DateTime -> DateTime -> Async<string>` and `t` and `s` are strings.

Any hints on why the compiler think I'm attempting to bind a `string` to a tuple of strings?

**Update:**

The root cause was actually in `getAuditEventsAsync` which does

```
async {
  return! Http.AsyncRequestString
            ( url, httpMethod="GET",
              headers = [ Accept        HttpContentTypes.Json;
                          Authorization "Bearer " + t ])
}
```

for some `url` and token `t` where both are strings.

[Operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) means that `Authorization "Bearer " + t` is interpreted as `(Authorization "Bearer ") + t`. `Authorization` returns `string * string`, (a non-overloaded) `+` is thus applied to a `string * string` and `string` which confuses the compiler.

The solution was to change `Authorization "Bearer " + t` to `Authorization ("Bearer " + t)`.

So the question is now: why is the compiler error thrown at the application of `getAuditEventsAsync` rather than `Authorization`? :)

Comment: What is the type of array `subs`?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, the compiler error is from the application of `getAuditEventsAsync` rather than from the binding/destructuring of `x`. Added clarification.

Comment: What is the type, reported by intellisense if you hover over getAuditEventsAsync function? Maybe you were "lucky" and the statement inside was somehow accepted and produced a funny type...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a minimal example giving the same error message:

```
let Accept a = "Accept", a
let foo x = Accept "hoo" + x

foo "z"
```

The compiler and editor report two error messages, but (for some reason unclear to me) F# Interactive reports only the one you were getting. One of the errors is for `+` inside `foo` and the other is when calling `foo`.

If you comment out the last line, you get just one error on `+`:

> error FS0071: Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type '(string * string)' for a type inference variable. Expecting a type supporting the operator '+' but given a tuple type Consider adding further type constraints

This makes sense and it says that `+` cannot be applied to tuples. Now, the compiler uses some defaulting mechanism so that it can continue type-checking and it decides that the argument of `foo` is also `string * string`. This then gives you the later error message when calling `foo`:

> error FS0001: The type 'string' does not match the type 'string * string'

The confusing thing is that when you uncomment the last line again, the error message for the body of `foo` also changes to:

> error FS0001: The type 'string' does not match the type 'string * string'

This is happening because the compiler now sees that `foo` is called with string as an argument and so the default guess `x : string * string` is replaced with `x : string`. I think this only affects the first error message though and so the second one still uses the default guess that `foo` takes `string * string`.

This is not entirely sensible behavior, but I guess that's the best the compiler can do given code with multiple errors - it has to use some default resolution for the error.